Obtain the class name on the detected output of picture YOLOV8
The identified picture displays a rectangular box with confidence even though the desired output is the class name and confidence:
screenshot
Regarding the YOLOV8 custom data model training, I had already produced a dataset and trained the nano, medium, and large YOLOV8 models. I obtained the runs to train result; nevertheless, the detected picture displays a rectangular box instead of the class name. What I expect is how I can display the detected Image with the class name?

Please check the model.names output for your model. Are the class names displayed properly and are they in English?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes, the class name is displayed properly but they are not in English
import yaml
Load your dataset YAML
with open('/content/data.yaml', 'r') as file:
data_yaml = yaml.safe_load(file)
Check the content
print(data_yaml['names'])
Output:
['ሀ', 'ሁ', 'ሂ', 'ሃ', 'ሄ', 'ህ', 'ሆ', 'ለ', 'ሉ', 'ሊ', 'ላ', 'ሌ', 'ል', 'ሎ']

@Guutaa Gammee, I suspect the problem is the yolov8 code fails to properly encode and display these symbols during prediction plotting, and therefore you see a rectangle instead of the symbols. For an experiment, try to change these symbols in the data.yaml for integers or Latin letters, then run the prediction mode. If these new symbols are displayed instead of the rectangle on a predicted image, the problem is in the text encoding.

Thank you! @hanna_liavoshka, It works with Latin letters and numbers; but, as you said, Yolo does not handle Amharic characters.s => ['ሀ', 'ሁ', 'ሂ', 'ሃ', 'ሄ', 'ህ', 'ሆ', 'ለ', 'ሉ', 'ሊ', 'ላ', 'ሌ', 'ል', 'ሎ']

Ultralytics uses cv2.putText() method to plot labels on images. This method more likely accepts only ASCII characters, so the solution for this case can be to write your only code for plotting labels, using detection results from yolov8.
